# Provide the namespace argument to include() instead on django 3.0

Tags: django, python-3.7

In Django 3.0 this gives the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.
```

How should I change `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`? I tried to look at the documentation,

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/', include(myapp.views)),
]
```

Comment: Use `path` or `re_path`, import them from `django.urls`. Which documentation did you look at? There's no `url` anymore.

Answer (score 3):

remove include from admin urls and use path

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('hello/', include('myapp.views')),
]
```

refer this [django 3 doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: where's the `include()`?

Comment: same for `admin`, it should `include()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `include(myapp.views)`:

- First you should include a string (`include('myapp.views')`), not the actual module. That's what is causing the error.
- But second, you don't include views, you include other url patterns. So unless `myapp.views` contains a top-level `urlpatterns`, you'll get an error as well.

Finally, as @c.grey pointed out, use `path()`, not `url()`.